# Form inside table or table inside form, which one is the right for valid Twitter Bootstrap markup?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a template based on Twitter Bootstrap and I have a doubt as title says: *Form inside table or table inside form, which one is the right for valid Twitter Bootstrap markup? Are both valid?*

**First markup:**

```
<form id="fabForm" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Col Title</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="fabLinkChoice[]" value="1">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>Dist1</td>                           
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="" id="btnAgregarSelFabricante"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Add</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Second markup:**

```
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Col Title</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                     <form id="fabForm" method="post">
                         <div class="form-group">
                             <tr>
                                  <td>
                                      <div class="checkbox">
                                           <label>
                                               <input type="checkbox" name="fabLinkChoice[]" value="1">
                                           </label>
                                     </div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td>Dist1</td>                           
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                 <td colspan="2">
                                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="" id="btnAgregarSelFabricante"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Add</button> 
                                 </td>
                             </tr>
                        </div>
                    </form>
               </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

**NOTE:** my doubt has a origin on [this code](http://pastie.org/9813404). There you'll notice the code of the first example and also it's on a Bootstrap Modal, but I can't get it look fine. This is what I see on Chrome:

[image]

And I don't know if I'm missing something in my markup. Around why I'm using tables is because is a tabular data and I think this is the right or I'm wrong?

Comment: This first one might be slightly better because the submit button is not in the table. This would allow more to re-flow for smaller screens

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [permitted contents of a `tbody` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tbody.html) are zero or more `tr` tags, so your second example is not valid HTML.

You could move your form inside a table cell, but more commonly you will see a table inside a form instead of vice versa.

It also appears from your limited examples that you may be using a table for layout purposes, which I would urge you to reconsider.

Comment: take a look to the note I leave on the main post, perhaps this clear my question a bit and help you understand why I use table for layout purposes, also if you can take a look to the code and tell me why I'm seeing the content on the modal wrong will be nice

Comment: If you're concerned about alignment, try removing the form-group, checkbox and label elements. For padding within the modal, make sure your content is within a div with class modal-content.

Comment: I can't remove them cause I'm using [BootstrapValidator](http://formvalidation.io/) plugin to validate choices, see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772774/validate-choice-checkbox-does-not-work-in-bootstrapvalidator) from my authority is related to this markup also

Comment: And yes, contents are inside a `div` with class `modal-content`, take a look to the code on pastie

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR: `<table>` *INSIDE* `<form>` is more common

```html
<form>
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
</form>
```